# Ajax if statement request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$("#Submit").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var th = '<tr><th>' + "Business" +'</th><th>' + "Address"+ '</th><th>'+ "Rating" + '</th><th>' + "Date" + '</th></tr>';
    $("#restaurants").empty().html(th);
    var Searching = $("#Search").val();
    $.ajax({
        type     : "GET",
        url      : "http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/lb514/hygiene/hygiene.php",
        dataType : "json",
        data     : {op : "searchname", name : Searching},
        success  : function(data){
            $.each(data,function(key,results){
                if(results.length > 1){
                    $("#restaurants").append(
                        "<tr><td>" + results.business +"</td>"+
                        "<td>" + results.address + "</td>" + 
                        "<td>" + results.rating + "</td>" + 
                        "<td>" + results.date + "</td></tr>"
                    )
                }else if( results.length  <  1){
                    alert("The search term ");
                }
            })
        }
    });
})
```

This is an AJAX request, called after the user press the submit button to search for a restaurant. Now for a better design I included `if` statement to check whether the callback object is empty but it doesnt work.
However, even with this I have tested and it works if you give a similar name to a restaurant. But it doesnt alert if you give a name that is not in the database and I don't see where I went wrong.

PS. I also tried `data.length`

Comment: Does your server return 200 OK if the result is empty?

Comment: Can you give an example of what should be in the search variables? Without them, it's currently returning "Empty search string"

Comment: When `results.length === 1` then your code do nothing. You should have something like `if(results.length){ ... }else{ ...alert...}`

Comment: If `data` is empty then `$.each` will have nothing to iterate through. So if it is possible for `data` to be empty then you should check for that before the `$.each` call.

Comment: Maybe check if results is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It's often helpful to have a complete working example, so here is my go. The following gives you a section to respond if your have 0 results. Although this doesn't cover all use cases as it's not 100% obvious how the php file you're accessing works.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <input type="text" id="Search">
    <button id="Submit">Submit</button>
    <div id="restaurants"></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $("#Submit").click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var th = '<tr><th>' + "Business" +'</th><th>' + "Address"+ '</th><th>'+ "Rating" + '</th><th>' + "Date" + '</th></tr>';
                $("#restaurants").empty().html(th);
                var Searching = $("#Search").val();
                $.ajax({
                 type : "GET",
                 url : "http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/lb514/hygiene/hygiene.php",
                 dataType : "json",
                 data : {op : "searchname", name : Searching},
                 success : function(data){
                     if(data.length == 0){
                         // what to do when nothing returns
                         alert("Nothing found");
                     }else{
                        $.each(data,function(key,results){
                            if(results.length > 1){
                             $("#restaurants").append(
                                         "<tr><td>" + results.business +"</td>"+
                                         "<td>" + results.address + "</td>" + 
                                         "<td>" + results.rating + "</td>" + 
                                         "<td>" + results.date + "</td></tr>")
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }});
              });
    </script>
</BODY>
```